# How can I RDP to a Hyper V virtual machine with Windows server 2022 standard

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, hyper-v

I have a dedicated server at CloudSouth running Windows server 2019. I have several dedicated IP addresses (virtual IP addresses) on my host machine for SSL purposes. I created a virtual machine running Windows 2022 on Hyper V. I assigned one of my virtual IP addresses to this virtual machine. I configured the virtual switch and IP address and my virtual machine is connected to the Internet. I have also opened up the http, https, and RDP ports on my Fortinet external firewall for the IP address assigned to my virtual machine. I am able to RDP on my host machine, but I am not able to RDP directly to my virtual machine from my home address which is at a different location than my host server. I have enabled RDP in server manager of the virtual machine. However, when I try to RDP using the IP address I have assigned to the virtual machine I'm unable to connect. Only way I am able to access the virtual machine is thru my main host by RDPing to the host machine and then connecting with Hyper V to the virtual machine. Is it actually possible to connect directly to my virtual machine from an external computer at a different location? What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps see if an external switch (static IP on your Hyper-V Host) helps.

Comment: When using Hyper-V to access it, is the VM able to browse the internet?